# Finding the last K in a singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, singly-linked-list, pseudocode

I have an algorithm that should take input k and return the corresponding k-th last element, so if k=1, it should return the last element, if k=2 if should return the second last element...and so on

I am not understanding what some of the lines of code are doing or why they need to be there such as:

```
n = n - k + 1
```

this is the entire code, any help understanding what each line is doing would be great:

```
function lastk(List L, Int k) → List 
  tmp = L
  n = 0
  while tmp ̸= NIL do
    n=n+1
    tmp = tmp.next 
  if n<k then
    return NIL 
  else
    tmp = L
    n = n − k + 1 
    i=1
    while i < n do
      tmp = tmp.next
      i=i+1 
    return tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `while` loop calculates the length of the list `L` returns `NIL` if this length is less than `k`.

Next two lines `else tmp = L` are redundant.

`n − k + 1` is the index of the `k`-th element from the end.

Second `while` loop traverses the list to this element.